# Probability of getting a number having last digit among 1,3,5,7 ,which is formed by multiplying randomly four numbers

Tags: probability

If any four numbers are selected and they are multiplied then the probability that their product will have the unit digit to be either $1,3,5,7$ is ?

> **My progress** :
> Since the sample space is not given i thought maybe taking it to be $1-100$ ? Thought i dont know whether this will give correct probability or not but atleast i can solve for a small version of the problem ,                       .
> The numbers should be first all odd otherwise any even coming will cause remainder to be a multiple of 2 not allowed . So now we have to check cases in which there is a $9$ unit digit coming from the modulo 10 residues $1,3,5,7,9$ .  By checking j found all cases are $3337, 7773 ,1133, 1999,1379,1177,1119,3399,7799$ where $9$ comes in unit digit . When multiples all four numbers having these residues modulo $10$ . So now from $1-100$ we take all $6$ cases and subtract the ones where $9$ unit digit comes ? Is my approach all correcy or something wrong ?

Comment: Just concern yourself with the final digits.   ... " I by checking all cases found that 3337,7773,1133,1999,1379,1177 are the cases where 9 comes in unit digit ."  I have *no* idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @fleablood I'd imagine that's shorthand for the collection of units digits of the numbers being multiplied, noting that $3\times 3\times 3\times 7 \equiv 9\pmod{10}$ for instance.  That said, the above is missing some cases such as 7799.  It should be clear that even numbers wont lead to a units digit of 9, similarly 5 won't either, as those are zero divisors in $\Bbb Z_{10}$

Comment: Oh... somehow I was missing that there were 4 and not 2 numbers being multiplied.

Comment: You only care about the final digits, so could restrict the sample space to $1-10$ or even $0-9$

Comment: I edited for three more cases  JMoravitz . @fleablood yeah i was considering last digit but the numbers total also needs to be concerned isnt ? As 1-45 would give different probability then 1-100 or 1-120 etc. .  though i think questions seems to tells us to considering the infinity of whole numbers , also does question meant to say we can use repitition ? Or  seems more like random different?

Comment: @Henry are we assuming the numbers can repeat ? Though its nothing mentioned but i thought randomly choosing four here would mean different numbers so maybe better sample space would be 1-40 as we can take four numbers of same modulo here ?

Comment: I would presume final digits can repeat, and the actual sample space was big enough so the probability of each final digit is $0-9$ close enough to uniform i.i.d.

Comment: @Paracetamol officially, we can not use "*the infinity of whole numbers*" directly since there can not (*per the axioms of probability*) exist a uniform distribution over a countably infinite set.  We can however note that the answer will be exactly or "*very close*" to my answer below for any probability space of the form $\{0,1,2,\dots,N\}$ with $N$ "*large*" and the specific answer for a given large $N$ will get closer and closer to that limit if $N$ gets even bigger (*if not in the case of it being exactly that answer in the case that $N$ is one less than a multiple of 10*)

Comment: @JMoravitz you mean for N = 10K-1 and as K goes to infinity the below answer matches , but for other N it diverts a bit but still close to the probabilitt we get from N = 10k-1 form ? And okay fine Henry

Comment: I feel loath to handwave the issues of an infinite sample space away, put my point was that only the final digits determine the final digit of the products you "might as well" take your sample space to just be the the sample space of the 10 final digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*since the sample space is not given...*"  It might as well be just picking from $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,9\}$ with repetition as this will give the same result as if it were picking from $\{0,1,2,\dots,10n-1\}$ for any $n$ and the same limiting probability if we were picking from $\{0,1,2,\dots,N\}$ as $N\to\infty$.

Let the four numbers in sequence be $a,b,c,d$.  Now... in order for the final product to have units digit equal to $9$ the following two things must be true:

- The first three numbers' can be anything so long as their units digits must have been chosen from $\{1,3,7,9\}$ (*since any others are zero divisors in $\Bbb Z_{10}$ and would make it impossible to have the final units' digit be a nine, i.e. would make the product even or a multiple of five*).  This will make it so that $a,b,c$ are all coprime to $10$.
- The fourth number $d$ must be equivalent to $9\times a^{-1}\times b^{-1}\times c^{-1}\pmod{10}$.  There is always exactly one possibility for $d$'s unit digit that will satisfy this.

So then, the probability that the first three numbers do not "mess it up" and that the fourth number has an odd digit matches exactly with the needed units digit to make the final result's unit digit a 9:

$$0.4^3\times 0.1$$

The probability that the numbers produce an odd final digit different than nine is then the probability all units digits were odd minus the above probability:

$$0.5^4 - 0.4^3\times 0.1$$

Comment: That final value is the probability the product ends with $9$.  You need to subtract that from the probability the product ends with an odd number

Comment: Good catch.  $~~$

Comment: Do you all agree if the random numbers were supposed to be "different" , is given in the original problem , we would have to take the smallest sample space to be of 1-40 ? And not 1-10 or maybe 0-39 and not 0-9 ?

Comment: If you are talking about "*without replacement*" then the smallest sample space possible is $\{1,2,3,4\}$... you'll just end up with an answer of zero.  In the case that we are doing this without replacement then no finite value of $n$ will have the sample space $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ have an answer exactly equal the above but the sequence of probabilities will converge to the answer above... essentially  because the more numbers there are to pick from the less likely we will have picked a duplicate to the point where any deviation caused by this can be ignored.

Comment: Since it is not mentioned what the sample space was and not mentioned whether repetition was allowed, I am of the opinion that the limit is indeed the answer they were after (*since that conforms to the naive [and flawed] interpretation of picking from an infinite set of numbers with or without repetition*)

Comment: Thanks i got the most part , one thing how we are finding the smallest space ? Is by looking at the uniform chance of numbers ? Like for without replacement i dont get how 1-4 is smallest and why not 1-40

Comment: @Paracetamol To emphasize... maybe the smallest sample space is just $\{1\}$... but if that were the sample space then the experiment would be impossible to carry out.  It would have been impossible to pick four numbers without repetition from that sample space and so it would be meaningless to ask a question about a probability corresponding to an experiment which could not possibly be performed.  At least with $\{1,2,3,4\}$ it becomes possible to perform the experiment of taking four numbers and multiplying them together... though the result of that experiment would not relate to larger $n$

Comment: As for why $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and not $\{1,2,3,\dots,40\}$?  Why is $\{1,2,3,4\}$ smaller?  Because... that is what smaller *means*... I hope I don't need to explain why $4<40$.  "*Is by looking at uniform chance of numbers?*"  I mean... sure, at least with $\{1,2,\dots,40\}$ the first chosen number has a uniform chance to be any of the numbers, as does the second... but those are not independent of one another which disrupts our calculations and makes things frustrating... again, a big part of why I advocate for the limit answer or the answer assuming repetition is allowed.

Comment: I see undestood, though by why 1,2,3,4 is smaller i was asking as if its valid smallest sample space to consider ,but i think now i get it how it was decided

Comment: Per Henry's comment, the solution is $0.5^4-0.4^3\times 0.1$